# How can I perform a pre-check transaction to verify if it will be successful without recording it on the blockchain?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, ethers.js

We aim to implement transaction checking, specifically for swaps, to ensure they won't be reverted. This will help users avoid unnecessary gas costs.

1. I want to do this on the front-end, using the ether.js library. Or any other library.

Comment: Not sure if this can help, but maybe you can look for the method estimateGas, https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-estimateGas. Maybe it fails if tx is reverted. Not sure.

Comment: From ethers you can use staticCall.